# Get stored wifi passwords in a device using python

Tags: python, wifi

I've tried to run this script to get all wifi passwords in a device but when i run it nothing happens.
just it even ran without errors.
os is windows
Here is the script

```py
import subprocess
import re


command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

profile_names = (re.findall("All User Profile       : (.*)\r", command_output))

wifi_list = list()

if len(profile_names) !=0:
    for name in profile_names:

        wifi_profile = dict()

        profile_info = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
 
        if re.search("Security Key      : Absent", profile_info):
            continue
        else:

            wifi_profile["ssid"] = name

            profile_info_pass = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

            password = re.search("Key Content       : (.*)\r", profile_info_pass)

            if password == None:
                wifi_profile["password"] = None

            else:
                wifi_profile["password"] = password[1]

            wifi_list.append(wifi_profile)


for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
    print(wifi_list[x])
```

Comment: hi there Dear Hosam: - first of all many thanks: for me it does not work - I am on Python 3.8.2 on anaconda: i get back    data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')

  File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,

  File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh' -what to do now!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once worked on this check this code

```
import subprocess

data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
profiles = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in data if "All User Profile" in i]
for i in profiles:
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 'key=clear']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if "Key Content" in b]
    try:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, ""))
input("")
```

Comment: hi there dear Bhargav - first of all many thanks: for me it does not work - I am on Python 3.8.2 on anaconda: i get back    data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')

  File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,

  File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh' -what to do now!?

Answer (score 0):

On my system the `re.search` lines have too many spaces. Try removing two spaces from each of them, e.g. `"Security Key         : Absent"` becomes `"Security Key       : Absent"`. A better solution would be to change it to cope with any number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

```
import subprocess as sp
import re

output = sp.getoutput(f'netsh wlan show profiles name=*')
wifi_name_list = []
for name_index in [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Name', output)]:
    wifi_name_list.append(output[name_index:name_index+output[name_index:].find('Control options')].split(':')[1].strip())

for name in wifi_name_list:
    output = sp.getoutput(f'netsh wlan show profile name="{name}" key=clear')
    output = output[output.find('Key Content'):output.find('Cost settings')]
    output = output[output.find(':')+2:]
    output = output.strip()
    print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(name, output))
```